# :first-child with nested elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to understand why li:first-child is targeting the first li (CHILD 1) and its children (GRANDCHILD 1.1, GRANDCHILD 1.2, GRANDCHILD 1.3) but about the others li children (CHILD 2 and CHILD 3) is targeting only its first child (GRANDCHILD 2.1 and GRANDCHILD 3.1)

HTML

```
<body>
    <ul>
      PARENT
      <li>CHILD 1
        <ul>
          <li>GRANDCHILD 1.1</li>
          <li>GRANDCHILD 1.2</li>
          <li>GRANDCHILD 1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>CHILD 2
        <ul>
          <li>GRANDCHILD 2.1</li>
          <li>GRANDCHILD 2.2</li>
          <li>GRANDCHILD 2.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>CHILD 3
        <ul>
          <li>GRANDCHILD 3.1</li>
          <li>GRANDCHILD 3.2</li>
          <li>GRANDCHILD 3.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
li:first-child {
  background: chartreuse;
}
```

Comment: The first <li> is the first child. So it is complete surrounded with  the bg-color and of course all its children. Which are all 1.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `border: 1px solid red;` it will show you the answer.

```
li:first-child {
  background: chartreuse;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Check it out here: https://codepen.io/riiiad/pen/dyppZdY

Comment: In this context is corret to afirm that GRANDCHILD 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 inherited its style from CHILD 1?

Comment: Not really. CHILD 1 is selected with your selector and as it is the container of the ul and li inside of it the other elemtens just look like the are having the same bg-color. But they dont have the same css.

Comment: I updated the answer with a link. @JeanCarlos

Comment: Now I have understood. Thanks!

Comment: @JeanCarlos Would mind marking the answer as helpful. Glad I could help.